# QGIS 3.16, 3.22. SAGA tools not working. ERROR: Loading resulting layers The following layers were not correctly generated

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, saga

I've tried multiple SAGA processing tools (Tools tried include: "clip raster with polygon". "Fill sinks Fill sinks (Wang and Liu)". "Polygon Centroids.". It seems that none are working and I always get the same error message: *"Loading resulting layers*
*The following layers were not correctly generated"*
I can't find the files in the directories where they should be saved.

I have tried reinstalling QGIS and switching from different versions and. I have tried to save the output-files in directories that lack spaces in their names. The CRS for inputfiles are the same as the project's (3006, Sweref 99TM). I have tried disabling "load upon completion".

I tried using the SAGA GUI also (the seperate SAGA programme outside of WGIS) and the analyses work there. I tried these two processes: and both work: "Fill sinks (Wang & Liu)" and "Polygon to centroids". When in QGIS and using "Polygon to centroids", trying to save as a shapefile results in the same error. However a prj-file is generated and saved in the directory but no other files are saved.

I have tried starting a new QGIS-project for doing the analyses and also tried to do the analyses on another computer through the Qgis version 3.16.4. Neither of these options worked.

I can't recall SAGA ever working for me in QGIS before but I'm not sure. Might have used it successfully a long time ago...

This is the full processing log:

```
"QGIS version: 3.22.14-Białowieża
QGIS code revision: 4cde646c
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.6.1
GEOS version: 3.11.1-CAPI-1.17.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.1.1, December 1st, 2022
PDAL version: 2.4.3 (git-version: f8d673)
SAGA version 7.8.2 is not officially supported - algorithms may encounter issues
Algorithm started at: 2022-12-27T22:07:41
Algorithm 'Clip Raster with Polygon' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'EXTENT' : 2, 'INPUT' : ['C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/OneDrive - Enviroplanning/MAPP MED TILLFÄLLIGT INNEHÅLL/Våtmark mossen 2022-2023/GIS/Data Hannes Privat/Modified DEM.tif'], 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'POLYGONS' : 'C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/OneDrive - Enviroplanning/MAPP MED TILLFÄLLIGT INNEHÅLL/Våtmark mossen 2022-2023/GIS/Data Hannes Privat/Vector1.shp' }
io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 3 -GRIDS "C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_CjnbZv/85069a35ab094eb6b63ba1f02a8d1916/ModifiedDEM.sgrd" -FILES "C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/OneDrive - Enviroplanning/MAPP MED TILLFÄLLIGT INNEHÅLL/Våtmark mossen 2022-2023/GIS/Data Hannes Privat/Modified DEM.tif"
shapes_grid "Clip Grid with Polygon" -INPUT "C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_CjnbZv/85069a35ab094eb6b63ba1f02a8d1916/ModifiedDEM.sgrd" -POLYGONS "C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/OneDrive - Enviroplanning/MAPP MED TILLFÄLLIGT INNEHÅLL/Våtmark mossen 2022-2023/GIS/Data Hannes Privat/Vector1.shp" -EXTENT 2 -OUTPUT "C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_CjnbZv/5add548c845a49a2b95b8c75a395691d/OUTPUT.sdat"
C:\Users\vilhelm.moran\Documents>set SAGA=C:/OSGeo4W/apps\saga
C:\Users\vilhelm.moran\Documents>set SAGA_MLB=C:/OSGeo4W/apps\saga\modules
C:\Users\vilhelm.moran\Documents>PATH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\lib;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qt5\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Scripts;C:\OSGeo4W\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBem;C:/OSGeo4W/apps\saga;C:/OSGeo4W/apps\saga\modules
C:\Users\vilhelm.moran\Documents>call saga_cmd io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 3 -GRIDS "C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_CjnbZv/85069a35ab094eb6b63ba1f02a8d1916/ModifiedDEM.sgrd" -FILES "C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/OneDrive - Enviroplanning/MAPP MED TILLFÄLLIGT INNEHÅLL/Våtmark mossen 2022-2023/GIS/Data Hannes Privat/Modified DEM.tif"
____________________________
##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________
SAGA Version: 7.8.2 (64 bit)
____________________________
library path: C:\OSGeo4W\apps\saga\tools\
library name: io_gdal
library : io_gdal
tool : Import Raster
identifier : 0
author : O.Conrad (c) 2007 (A.Ringeler)
processors : 4 [4]
____________________________
Execution completed in 9.38 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_CjnbZv/5add548c845a49a2b95b8c75a395691d/OUTPUT.sdat'}
Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_CjnbZv/5add548c845a49a2b95b8c75a395691d/OUTPUT.sdat
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm."
```

Comment: It looks like you are saving to a temporary output. It might help if you specify a save location.

Comment: If you save to a shapefile does it work?  If you run the SAGA tool(s) from the SAGA GUI (admittedly not as easy to use as QGIS but this is more of a test) do you get expected results?

Comment: @john I tried using the SAGA GUI now and the analyses work there. I tried these two processes: and both work: "Fill sinks (Wang & Liu)" and "Polygon to centroids".

When in QGIS and using "Polygon to centroids", trying to save as a shapefile results in the same error. However a prj-file is generated and saved in the directory but no other files are saved.

Comment: @Matt I have tried to save in a location but it didn't work either. The same error appears.

Comment: My other thought was that perhaps it's because there is a `.` in your filepath. I don't know how fussy SAGA is about directory names.

Comment: @Matt I tried saving it on another path without dots in the pathway now and it didn't work.

Comment: I just ran the polygon to centroids tool in QGIS on some selected polygons and it worked fine saving to a temp file.  I checked my plugins and the core one for SAGA by Victor Olaya is checked.  I also have an unchecked version of one by Bruy which is no longer available.

Comment: changing the location of the working directory solved my problem too (untill the next one hehe), thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got all previously tried SAGA tools to work. How did I do it? It seems that SAGA could not handle the directory of my input files. When I moved the input files to other directories and then ran them with the SAGA tools within QGIS everything worked fine. All I need to do now is to set up a different working folder for my future projects.

This is one of the successfull processing logs:

```
QGIS version: 3.22.14-Białowieża
QGIS code revision: 4cde646c
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.6.1
GEOS version: 3.11.1-CAPI-1.17.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.1.1, December 1st, 2022
PDAL version: 2.4.3 (git-version: f8d673)
SAGA version 7.8.2 is not officially supported - algorithms may encounter issues
Algorithm started at: 2022-12-29T09:38:20
Algorithm 'Fill Sinks (Wang & Liu)' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'ELEV' : 'C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/Desktop/test 2.tif', 'FDIR' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'FILLED' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'MINSLOPE' : 0.1, 'WSHED' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 3 -GRIDS "C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_uKqhid/a9325f0e0ded4c83a778f2a520ebe29f/test2.sgrd" -FILES "C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/Desktop/test 2.tif"
ta_preprocessor "Fill Sinks (Wang & Liu)" -ELEV "C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_uKqhid/a9325f0e0ded4c83a778f2a520ebe29f/test2.sgrd" -MINSLOPE 0.1 -FILLED "C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_uKqhid/1e55d5ac4ec148c1b41d5174ddb46921/FILLED.sdat" -FDIR "C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_uKqhid/25cb9a3bba6b40d8bf808be78f34b048/FDIR.sdat" -WSHED "C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_uKqhid/31c1f7c96d584ab8a2880adeec5b0f7b/WSHED.sdat"

C:\Users\vilhelm.moran\Documents>set SAGA=C:/OSGeo4W/apps\saga

C:\Users\vilhelm.moran\Documents>set SAGA_MLB=C:/OSGeo4W/apps\saga\modules

C:\Users\vilhelm.moran\Documents>PATH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\lib;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass78\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qt5\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Scripts;C:\OSGeo4W\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBem;C:/OSGeo4W/apps\saga;C:/OSGeo4W/apps\saga\modules

C:\Users\vilhelm.moran\Documents>call saga_cmd io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 3 -GRIDS "C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_uKqhid/a9325f0e0ded4c83a778f2a520ebe29f/test2.sgrd" -FILES "C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/Desktop/test 2.tif"
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 7.8.2 (64 bit)

____________________________
library path: C:\OSGeo4W\apps\saga\tools\
library name: io_gdal
library : io_gdal
tool : Import Raster
identifier : 0
author : O.Conrad (c) 2007 (A.Ringeler)
processors : 4 [4]
____________________________



Parameters


Grids: No objects
Files: "C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/Desktop/test 2.tif"
Multiple Bands Output: automatic
Select from Multiple Bands:
Transformation: true
Resampling: B-Spline Interpolation
Extent: original


loading: C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/Desktop/test 2.tif



Driver: GTiff

Bands: 1

Rows: 5000

Columns: 5000


loading: test 2


Saving grid: C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_uKqhid/a9325f0e0ded4c83a778f2a520ebe29f/test2.sgrd...



C:\Users\vilhelm.moran\Documents>call saga_cmd ta_preprocessor "Fill Sinks (Wang & Liu)" -ELEV "C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_uKqhid/a9325f0e0ded4c83a778f2a520ebe29f/test2.sgrd" -MINSLOPE 0.1 -FILLED "C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_uKqhid/1e55d5ac4ec148c1b41d5174ddb46921/FILLED.sdat" -FDIR "C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_uKqhid/25cb9a3bba6b40d8bf808be78f34b048/FDIR.sdat" -WSHED "C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_uKqhid/31c1f7c96d584ab8a2880adeec5b0f7b/WSHED.sdat"
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 7.8.2 (64 bit)

____________________________
library path: C:\OSGeo4W\apps\saga\tools\
library name: ta_preprocessor
library : ta_preprocessor
tool : Fill Sinks (Wang & Liu)
identifier : 4
author : Copyrights (c) 2007 by Volker Wichmann
processors : 4 [4]
____________________________

Loading grid: C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_uKqhid/a9325f0e0ded4c83a778f2a520ebe29f/test2.sgrd...




Parameters


Grid System: 1; 5000x 5000y; 295000.5x 6510000.5y
DEM: test2
Filled DEM:
Flow Directions:
Watershed Basins:
Minimum Slope [Degree]: 0.100000





Saving grid: C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_uKqhid/25cb9a3bba6b40d8bf808be78f34b048/FDIR.sdat...


Saving grid: C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_uKqhid/31c1f7c96d584ab8a2880adeec5b0f7b/WSHED.sdat...



C:\Users\vilhelm.moran\Documents>exit
Execution completed in 55.59 seconds
Results:
{'FDIR': 'C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_uKqhid/25cb9a3bba6b40d8bf808be78f34b048/FDIR.sdat',
'FILLED': 'C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_uKqhid/1e55d5ac4ec148c1b41d5174ddb46921/FILLED.sdat',
'WSHED': 'C:/Users/vilhelm.moran/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_uKqhid/31c1f7c96d584ab8a2880adeec5b0f7b/WSHED.sdat'}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Fill Sinks (Wang & Liu)' finished
```

I will say however that it's a bit surprising that if I open the SAGA gui (separated from QGIS) and run the SAGA tools from there I don't need to change directories.