# Unable to run SAGA-Terrain Analysis-Fill sinks (wang&liu)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, saga, watershed

I am trying to do a Watershed analysis using QGIS. However if I want to run the SAGA function Fill sinks (Wang & Liu) I get an error that the 3 files were not created (full error down below). I have tried different Long term Release QGIS versions 3.16 and 3.22 resulting in the same problem. Also changing/setting other file paths as suggested here ([QGIS 3.16, 3.22. SAGA tools not working. ERROR: Loading resulting layers The following layers were not correctly generated](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/448466/qgis-3-16-3-22-saga-tools-not-working-error-loading-resulting-layers-the-fol)) was not doing the job either.

[image: Protokol]

```
QGIS-Version: 3.16.0-Hannover
QGIS-Codeversion: 43b64b13f3
Qt-Version: 5.11.2
GDAL-Version: 3.1.4
GEOS-Version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ-Version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Verarbeite Algorithmus…
Algorithmus Fill sinks (wang & liu) startet…
Eingabeparameter:
{ 'ELEV' : 'X:/Hydrologen/Gauss/Schwarzbach/Eigene/gsk3_SWB_dgm_manipuliert.tif', 'FDIR' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'FILLED' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'MINSLOPE' : 0.01, 'WSHED' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }


io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 3 -GRIDS "C:/Users/J.Gauß/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_slldFZ/d57cfc8770534440bbff91b5347b3f81/gsk3SWBdgmmanipuliert.sgrd" -FILES "X:/Hydrologen/Gauss/Schwarzbach/Eigene/gsk3_SWB_dgm_manipuliert.tif"
ta_preprocessor "Fill Sinks (Wang & Liu)" -ELEV "C:/Users/J.Gauß/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_slldFZ/d57cfc8770534440bbff91b5347b3f81/gsk3SWBdgmmanipuliert.sgrd" -MINSLOPE 0.01 -FILLED "C:/Users/J.Gauß/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_slldFZ/0de33c8a971c42c9b2078d856c0de09c/FILLED.sdat" -FDIR "C:/Users/J.Gauß/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_slldFZ/674262b25d114b6fba52f51e18d52e66/FDIR.sdat" -WSHED "C:/Users/J.Gauß/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_slldFZ/451b133bb4614170a667a3f717aac52d/WSHED.sdat"

Ausführung nach 15.73 Sekunden abgeschlossen
Ergebnisse:
{'FDIR': 'C:/Users/J.Gauß/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_slldFZ/674262b25d114b6fba52f51e18d52e66/FDIR.sdat',
'FILLED': 'C:/Users/J.Gauß/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_slldFZ/0de33c8a971c42c9b2078d856c0de09c/FILLED.sdat',
'WSHED': 'C:/Users/J.Gauß/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_slldFZ/451b133bb4614170a667a3f717aac52d/WSHED.sdat'}


Lade Ergebnis Layer
Die folgenden Layer wurden nicht erzeugt.
• C:/Users/J.Gauß/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_slldFZ/092cec3d31af409bb4f8e9675a21481c/WSHED.sdat
• C:/Users/J.Gauß/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_slldFZ/611d011ce68a4929a9f49c79c0d38d35/FDIR.sdat
• C:/Users/J.Gauß/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_slldFZ/6a63b0972d1b48538e30ebceacc685e4/FDIR.sdat
• C:/Users/J.Gauß/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_slldFZ/d0bbd605853f473081f6eb960a468ccb/FILLED.sdat
• C:/Users/J.Gauß/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_slldFZ/df04b0ea900c46b09032442f669d54f4/WSHED.sdat
• C:/Users/J.Gauß/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_slldFZ/e56106f039004b8b8f6bc056bff0a3ef/FILLED.sdat
Im 'Protokoll-Fenster' im QGIS-Hauptfenster sind mehr Informationen zur Ausführung des Algorithmus zu finden.
```

Comment: Recently tried update on 3.22 LTR qgis version. Still same error

Comment: Can you run the tool from the SAGA GUI?  That should have been installed with QGIS.  I know it's not as user friendly and has a bit of a learning curve but if it works you got something you can use and some info re the QGIS tool/plugin.