# The following layers were not correctly generated grid calculator

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, saga

I'm doing an assignment for a mapping class and I'm literally stuck trying to create a DEM file using the grid calculator under SAGA. I'm following the directions we were given and I have searched for other solutions such as saving as a temporary file and cleaning out my hard drive and I still get the error the layers were generated.

I'm a beginner using QGIS since I'm in an entry-level class. I've read other solutions but nothing is working and I have to do this step to make this mosaic DEM map for a grade. (copy and pasting the error) any solution would help because I'm at a loss.

I have the parameters set as 0 nearest neighbor, used a formula, and the data type as [7] 4 byte floating point number. I have my two layers used in our worksheet set as the grids.

```
Loading grid: C:/Users/Teacher/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_tNMXFy/c32f3ca4989242079cab7861bca39c93/RasterAnalysis.sgrd...
failed
Loading grid: C:/Users/Teacher/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_tNMXFy/0746117e2d3f4f80a1f93191f603be24/Vallwy9to3.sgrd...
failed
Grid Calculator: could not initialize data objects
Error: executing tool [Grid Calculator]

C:\Users\Teacher\Documents>exit
Execution completed in 9.86 seconds
Results:
{'RESULT': 'C:/Users/Teacher/Desktop/combineDEM.sdat'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/Teacher/Desktop/combineDEM.sdat
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Comment: Have you seen this thread yet and tried loading from a folder closer to the root C drive and/or using shorter file names?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/448466/qgis-3-16-3-22-saga-tools-not-working-error-loading-resulting-layers-the-fol?rq=1